# secret default-token mount leak while running kubernetes in docker

Tags: kubernetes

After starting kubernetes from this guide: http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker/ I get a lot of unused mount points on my node.  It seems to depend on how many pods are running.  Just now I had to unmount over 2600 mount points.  When these build up it causes findmnt to take a lot of resources to run.  The mount entries look like this:

```
tmpfs on /var/lib/kubelet/pods/599d6157-081e-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-kkzha type tmpfs (rw)
```

Does anybody know why these are not getting unmounted automatically?  From the tutorial it seems to anticipate that you will have to clean some of these up (look under the **Turning down your cluster** section), but this seems excessive.  A few days ago I had to clean up 22,000 or so of them because I had a mongo cluster and redis running for a while.

--- UPDATE ---
After purging my system of the unused mounts, and waiting a few minutes, findmnt produces entries like this:

```
├─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/02929977-0812-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-kkzha             tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
│ └─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/02929977-0812-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-kkzha           tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
│   └─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/02929977-0812-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-kkzha         tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
│     └─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/02929977-0812-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-kkzha       tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
│       └─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/02929977-0812-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-kkzha     tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
│         └─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/02929977-0812-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-kkzha   tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
│           └─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/02929977-0812-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-kkzha tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
├─/var/lib/docker/containers/c84ad9b0f2ec580bedef394aa46bb147ed6c4f1e9454cd3729459d9127c0986e/shm                         shm                             tmpfs               rw,nosuid,nodev,noe
├─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/0eb8631e-0810-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-2vjia             tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
│ └─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/0eb8631e-0810-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-2vjia           tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
│   └─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/0eb8631e-0810-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-2vjia         tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
│     └─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/0eb8631e-0810-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-2vjia       tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
│       └─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/0eb8631e-0810-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-2vjia     tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
│         └─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/0eb8631e-0810-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-2vjia   tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
│           └─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/0eb8631e-0810-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-2vjia tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
├─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/fae71387-08aa-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-kkzha             tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
│ └─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/fae71387-08aa-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-kkzha           tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
│   └─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/fae71387-08aa-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-kkzha         tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
│     └─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/fae71387-08aa-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-kkzha       tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
│       └─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/fae71387-08aa-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-kkzha     tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
│         └─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/fae71387-08aa-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-kkzha   tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
│           └─/var/lib/kubelet/pods/fae71387-08aa-11e6-a512-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-kkzha tmpfs                           tmpfs               rw,relatime
├─/var/lib/docker/containers/5392d49f5140274ddcfbe757cf6a07336aa60975f3ea122d865a3b80f5540c1f/shm
```

-- Update #2 -- This is how I am starting kubelet

```
ARCH=amd64
DNS_IP=10.0.0.10
K8S_VERSION=$(curl -sS https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)


docker run \
    --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
    --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
    --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:rw \
    --volume=/var/lib/kubelet/:/var/lib/kubelet:rw \
    --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
    --net=host \
    --pid=host \
    --privileged=true \
    --name=kubelet \
    -d \
    gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube-${ARCH}:${K8S_VERSION} \
    /hyperkube kubelet \
        --containerized \
        --hostname-override="127.0.0.1" \
        --address="0.0.0.0" \
        --api-servers=http://localhost:8080 \
        --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests \
        --cluster-dns=$DNS_IP \
        --cluster-domain=cluster.local \
        --allow-privileged=true --v=2
```

In looking at some other suggestions (thanks Thibault Deheurles), I tried removing --containerized and --volume=/:/rootfs:ro, but that caused k8s to not start at all.

-- UPDATE #3 --
I tried adding the mount flag ,shared to my /var/lib/kubelet volume command, it now looks like this:

> --volume=/var/lib/kubelet/:/var/lib/kubelet:rw,shared

This didn't make a difference.

However, I noticed while tailing my kubelet docker container's logs, that this message occurs every time I get a new mount...

```
2016-04-26T20:30:52.447842722Z I0426 20:30:52.447559   21740 nsenter_mount.go:185] Failed findmnt command for path /var/lib/kubelet/pods/6bc8072c-0be9-11e6-b3e6-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/etcd-storage: exit status 1
```

Failed GC comment also appears in log...  Here are a few more entries

```
2016-04-26T20:38:11.436858475Z E0426 20:38:11.436757   21740 kubelet.go:956] Image garbage collection failed: non-existent label "docker-images"
2016-04-26T20:38:12.448049454Z I0426 20:38:12.447852   21740 nsenter_mount.go:185] Failed findmnt command for path /var/lib/kubelet/pods/1df6a8b4d6e129d5ed8840e370203c11/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/varetcd: exit status 1
2016-04-26T20:38:52.448175137Z I0426 20:38:52.447949   21740 nsenter_mount.go:185] Failed findmnt command for path /var/lib/kubelet/pods/d95a6048198f747c5fcb74ee23f1f25c/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/data: exit status 1
2016-04-26T20:39:14.447892769Z I0426 20:39:14.447649   21740 nsenter_mount.go:185] Failed findmnt command for path /var/lib/kubelet/pods/6bc8072c-0be9-11e6-b3e6-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/etcd-storage: exit status 1
2016-04-26T20:39:28.441137221Z I0426 20:39:28.440920   21740 nsenter_mount.go:185] Failed findmnt command for path /var/lib/kubelet/pods/1df6a8b4d6e129d5ed8840e370203c11/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/varetcd: exit status 1
2016-04-26T20:40:20.441118739Z I0426 20:40:20.441018   21740 nsenter_mount.go:185] Failed findmnt command for path /var/lib/kubelet/pods/d95a6048198f747c5fcb74ee23f1f25c/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/data: exit status 1
2016-04-26T20:40:22.447832573Z I0426 20:40:22.447590   21740 nsenter_mount.go:185] Failed findmnt command for path /var/lib/kubelet/pods/6bc8072c-0be9-11e6-b3e6-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/etcd-storage: exit status 1
2016-04-26T20:40:53.447612605Z I0426 20:40:53.447534   21740 nsenter_mount.go:185] Failed findmnt command for path /var/lib/kubelet/pods/1df6a8b4d6e129d5ed8840e370203c11/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/varetcd: exit status 1
2016-04-26T20:41:27.449053007Z I0426 20:41:27.448820   21740 nsenter_mount.go:185] Failed findmnt command for path /var/lib/kubelet/pods/d95a6048198f747c5fcb74ee23f1f25c/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/data: exit status 1
2016-04-26T20:41:30.440974280Z I0426 20:41:30.440889   21740 nsenter_mount.go:185] Failed findmnt command for path /var/lib/kubelet/pods/6bc8072c-0be9-11e6-b3e6-0090f5ea551f/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/etcd-storage: exit status 1
2016-04-26T20:41:58.441001603Z I0426 20:41:58.440906   21740 nsenter_mount.go:185] Failed findmnt command for path /var/lib/kubelet/pods/1df6a8b4d6e129d5ed8840e370203c11/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/varetcd: exit status 1
```

-- UPDATE #4 -- 
@PaulMorie asked about the mount/findmnt versions

```
$ which findmnt
/bin/findmnt

$ uname -a
Linux andromeda 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

$ dpkg -L mount | grep findmn
/usr/share/man/man8/findmnt.8.gz
/bin/findmnt

$ dpkg -l mount
ii  mount                                2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7    amd64                   Tools for mounting and manipulating filesystems
```

-- UPDATE #5 -- @tsaarni asked what I did to solve this problem...  Here is my hack

```
[eric@andromeda [feature/k8s-packaging-openvpn]util]$ cat clean-mounts.sh 
#!/bin/bash
counter=0
for  m in $( mount| grep secret | awk '{print $3}' ); do 
    sudo umount $m
    counter=$[counter + 1]
done
echo "cleaned $counter mounts"


[eric@andromeda [feature/k8s-packaging-openvpn]util]$ cat clean-mounts-watcher.sh 
#!/bin/bash
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd)"
while : ; do $DIR/clean-mounts.sh ; sleep 60; done
```

Comment: From inside the container where the kubelet is running, please share the output of `findmnt -o +PROPAGATION`

Comment: Unfortunately I am on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS and my findmnt does not have that option.

Comment: Running: findmnt > findmnt.txt
is producing a massive file, it is currently at 21G

Comment: These seem to be serviceaccount secrets that keep getting mounted from my local node into my pod's environment.  The pods only show one secret mountpoint at any given time.  Running df on my node doesn't show the mount points, but running mount does.  Running findmnt seems to be in some sort of a loop because of these.  I'll update my question showing what I see a few minutes after unmounting the unused ones.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I know what's going on.  Can you confirm which docker version you're using?

Comment: Also, please confirm how you're starting the kubelet container.

Comment: curl -sS https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt
v1.2.3

Comment: @PaulMorie, I edited my question to show how I am starting kubelet.  Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to change `--volume=/var/lib/kubelet/:/var/lib/kubelet:rw` to `--volume=/var/lib/kubelet/:/var/lib/kubelet:rw,shared`

Comment: @PaulMorie I put in the shared flag and unfortunately the mounts are still accumulating.  I started watching the kubelet logs and I'll post what I found above...  It seems related.

Comment: Interesting @rideswitch, that might be a bug.  what's the path of the findmnt binary on the host?

Comment: @PaulMorie
ouch, comment munged... putting the info on mount in the question

Comment: @rideswitch did you find fix for this problem?

Comment: @tsaarni You won't like it... I made a watcher loop to unmount the unused mounts... I'll post it above.

Answer (score 0):

The docker tutorial is outdated for now. You need to add some element on how to run the different services.

The last working version for me was [this one](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/4869#issuecomment-194149162)

Comment: Yea, that one didn't work for me.  k8s wouldn't even start.